# dynamically add textview on top of imageview android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to place textview on top of an imageview in android. Imageview is displaying a bitmap and I want to place textview on the top of imageview. 
I also want that wherever the imageview is touched, textview must appear there.What is the best way to go about doing that. Thanks

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/ll"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_image2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"

    />



</LinearLayout>
```

// my activity

```
 switch (action) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                        Bitmap.Config config = bm.getConfig();
                        int width = bm.getWidth();
                        int height = bm.getHeight();


                           bm2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, config);
                           c = new Canvas(bm2);

                           c.drawBitmap(bm, 0, 0, null);

                        iv2.setImageBitmap(bm2);
                    }


                    break;
```

Comment: `addView(view, position);` ?

Comment: could you please help with the code ?

Comment: Better use Relative layout

Comment: You can do that **in the layout**, by using a **compound drawable** for a TextView (so getting rid of the ImageView at all). Just use `android:drawableBottom="@drawable/your_image"` to set an image BELOW the text.

Comment: But wouldn't that restrict the textview to one place and I want to be able to change it's position on touch

Comment: The TextView remains moveable. And it carries the image with it (they are 1 thing).

Comment: Let us know if you got what you were looking for with the answers we gave or if you need something else, and remember accept the answer :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it from different approaches like this one, using RealtiveLayout:

First the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then the activity code:

```
public class LogDetailActivity extends Activity {

    TextView mTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_log_detail);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        mTextView.setText("Example Text");

        mTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your second problem! I haven't tested this code, but it should work:

Make sure you add `implements View.OnTouchListener` to your class declaration!

```
imageView.setOnTouchListener(this);

// later on the in the code, add this method

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    switch(v.getId()) {

        case R.id.imageViewId:

            float xPosition = event.getX();
            float yPosition = event.getY();

            textView.setX(xPosition);
            textView.setY(yPosition);

            break;

    }

}
```

Also, make the changes to the XML that 0mach0 suggested.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use constraint layout and define your `Imageview` as per below.

```
   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/arrangementImageView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

2. You need to make imageView listen to onTouchListener

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_arrangement);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    panelLayout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.panelLayout);
    arrangementImageView = findViewById(R.id.arrangementImageView);

    arrangementImageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            int offsetX = 10; // Up to you to set
            int offsetY = 10;

            TextView myObj = new    TextView(v.getContext().getApplicationContext());
            myObj.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.myImage, 0, 0, 0);
            myObj.setTextViewId(1001);
            panelLayout.addView(myObj, -1);

            ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();

            set.clone(panelLayout);
            set.connect(myObj.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, panelLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, (int) event.getRawY() - offsetY);
            set.connect(myObj.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, panelLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, (int) event.getRawX() - offsetX);
            set.applyTo(panelLayout);

            break;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```